# XML Parsing and HashMap storing: message is cut after apostrophe

Tags: android, hashmap, xml-parsing, saxparser

When I parse following XML and store it in HashMap the message is cut after (**'**) this symbol.

Ex. Message: "Hey amar! What's up?". it cut like this.

- message =(3577): Hey amar! What
- message =(3577): '
- message =(3577): s up?

**The final out put is : message = "s up?"**

**So how to solve this problem ?**

**HashMap's for Shoring XML DATA :**

```
public static HashMap<String,String> message_map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
public static HashMap<String,String> message_map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
public static HashMap<String,String> message_map3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

**XML:**

```
<statuses type="array">
 <status>
  <messageinfo>
    <messageid>485</messageid>
    <userid>58</userid>
    **<message>Hey amar! What's up?</message>**
  </messageinfo>
 <messageinfo>
    <messageid>486</messageid>
    <userid>58</userid>
    **<message>Hey What's up?</message>**
  </messageinfo>
 <messageinfo>
    <messageid>485</messageid>
    <userid>58</userid>
    **<message>What's up?</message>**
  </messageinfo>
 </status>
</statuses>
```

**code:**

```
package com.xmldataparser;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import android.util.Log;

public class Message_XHandler extends DefaultHandler 
{
     boolean in_porf_msg_statuses;
     boolean in_prof_msg_status;
     boolean in_prof_msg_messageinfo;
     boolean in_prof_msg_messageid;
     boolean in_prof_msg_userid;
     boolean in_prof_msg_message;

    int i=0;
    public String key = "";
    public String value = "";

    XMLData xml_message;

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        super.startDocument();
        xml_message = new XMLData();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
    {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("statuses"))
        {
            in_porf_msg_statuses= true;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("status"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_status = true;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("messageinfo"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_messageinfo = true;
            i++;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("messageid"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_messageid = true;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("userid"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_userid = true;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("message"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_message = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException 
    {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        String chars = new String(ch,start,length);
        chars = chars.trim();

        else if(in_prof_msg_messageid)
        {   
            if(i==1)
                {
                    xml_message.message_map1.put("messageid", chars);
                }
            else if(i==2)
                 {
                xml_message.message_map2.put("messageid", chars);
                 }
            else if(i==3)
             {
                xml_message.message_map3.put("messageid", chars);
             }  
            Log.v("messageid = ", chars);
        } 
        else if(in_prof_msg_userid)
        {   
            if(i==1)
                {
                    xml_message.message_map1.put("userid", chars);
                }
            else if(i==2)
                 {
                xml_message.message_map2.put("userid", chars);
                 }
            else if(i==3)
             {
                xml_message.message_map3.put("userid", chars);
             }  

                Log.v("userid = ", chars);
        } 
        else if(in_prof_msg_message)
        {   
            if(i==1)
                {
                xml_message.message_map1.put("message", chars);
                }
            else if(i==2)
                 {
                    xml_message.message_map2.put("message", chars);
                 }
            else if(i==3)
                 {
                    xml_message.message_map3.put("message", chars);
                 }  

                Log.v("message = ", chars);

        } 


        } 


    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException 
    {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("statuses"))
        {
            in_porf_msg_statuses = false;
        }

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("messageinfo"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_messageinfo = false;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("messageid"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_messageid = false;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("userid"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_userid= false;
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("message"))
        {
            in_prof_msg_message = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        super.endDocument();
    }

    public XMLData getProfileMessageData()
    {
        Log.v("WHERE","Message_XHandler getProfileMessageData()");
        return xml_message;
    }
}
```

**Problem :**
Log: 
07-04 13:38:37.924: VERBOSE/message =(3577): Hey amar! What
07-04 13:38:37.934: VERBOSE/message =(3577): '
07-04 13:38:37.934: VERBOSE/message =(3577): s up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Don Roby Answered..

Take a String variable and add in your map at endElement() method where your in_message variable goes false.
For Example do this...

```
String str = "";
```

//In characters() Method
else if(in_message)
{
 str += chars;
}
//In endElement() Method

else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("message"))
{
   in_message = false;
   map.put("message", str);
   Log.i("map "+i," message = "+str);
  str = "";
}
`

Answer (score 2):

The `characters` method can be called multiple times by the parser, supplying only part of the characters inside a given tag on each call.

This code does not allow for that happening.

What you have to do is setup a string buffer in the `startElement` method, collect characters into it in the `characters` and extract the string result in the `endElement` method.

Comment: hello Don Roby ,  Thanks for help. i am beginner in Android.  if you have code please post it.